# Import all CSV files that I select to Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, xampp

I have some PHP code to import CSV data to Mysql. It works correctly but this code will only work for a particular file named `trendspry.csv`. I want to add code so that my program can select and import a file from any directory.

I used:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

But when I print this, it always displays:

```
C:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpABDC
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my full code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $connect = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
    if (!$connect) {
        die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $cid = mysql_select_db('ts_order_track', $connect);
    $q = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'trendspry.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE tsd_orders
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        ( order_id, customer_id, firstname, lastname, email, telephone, mobile, shipping_firstname, shipping_lastname, shipping_mobile, shipping_address_1, shipping_address_2, shipping_city, shipping_zone, shipping_postcode, shipping_country, shipping_method, payment_method, payment_code, weight, date_added, date_modified, import_order_id, sub_total, shipping_charges, tax_charges, total, order_status, courier, awb_code, coupon_amount, coupon_code, product_name, product_sku, product_model, product_quantity, product_price )";
    $s = mysql_query($q, $connect);
    echo "$q";
    echo "File data successfully imported to database!!"; 
    mysql_close($connect);
}
?>
```

I want to change my program to work for all the files that I select.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter for the filename:

```
$filename="abc.csv";
```

and concatenate that in the $q:

```
$cid =mysql_select_db('ts_order_track',$connect);
    $q="LOAD DATA INFILE '".$filename."' REPLACE INTO TABLE tsd_orders
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    ( order_id, customer_id, firstname, lastname, email, telephone, mobile, shipping_firstname, shipping_lastname, shipping_mobile, shipping_address_1, shipping_address_2, shipping_city, shipping_zone, shipping_postcode, shipping_country, shipping_method, payment_method, payment_code, weight, date_added, date_modified, import_order_id, sub_total, shipping_charges, tax_charges, total, order_status, courier, awb_code, coupon_amount, coupon_code, product_name, product_sku, product_model, product_quantity, product_price )";
    $s=mysql_query($q, $connect );
   echo "$q";
```

The file name from the post is correct: the file names are always temporary, so you can either use that or retrieve the real file name.

Comment: what is abc.csv here??

Comment: how to define abc.csv??

Comment: Have comma separated file with columns enclosed in double quotes. In his example the first row is ignored and assumed to be column names. Csv means comma separated values

Comment: You don't need to hardcode filename in code. His was a placeholder. Yours would be from POST

Comment: hey sorry.. but i didn't understand. I want to use $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] here but I dont know how to use..